# Plank stopping time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> **Problem**: A plank of length $L$ and mass $m$ lies on a frictionless floor, if the plank has an initial velocity $v$, what is the stopping time of the block if it meets a floor with friction constant $\mu$.

[image: Problem Diagram]

My attempt:

I took a little piece of block with mass $\Delta m$, we know that $\Delta m = m\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}$.

Now if I apply the Newton laws in this piece, I get the following equation:

$$N_{piece}= \Delta mg $$

Thus my friction is $f_r=\mu\Delta mg$

If I apply Newton laws to the whole plank, I get:

$$-f_r=ma$$
$$\mu\Delta mg=ma$$
$$\mu mg\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}=ma$$

$$a=\mu g\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}$$

I have this equation, but I don't know how to relate it with time.

Comment: You're nearly there. If we replace $\Delta \ell$ by $x$ for convenience, and note that $a = -\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$, then we get $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\frac{\mu g}{L} x$, which is just the differential equation describing a simple harmonic oscillator.

Comment: So,  a Plank moves farther than the Planck Distance!  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Can you be certain of that?