# Plank stopping time (Continuation and Physical meaning)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A while back I asked this problem: "[Plank stopping time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121325/plank-stopping-time)"

I thought it was solved, but now I have some questions about the solution.

> **Problem**: A plank of length $L$ and mass $m$ lies on a frictionless floor, if the plank has an initial velocity $v$, what is the stopping time of the block if it meets a floor with friction constant $\mu$.
>   [image: Problem Diagram]

So my previous solution is as follows:

I took a little piece of block with mass $\Delta m$, we know that $\Delta m = m\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}$.

Now if I apply the Newton laws in this piece, I get the following equation:

$$N_{\text{piece}}= \Delta mg $$

Thus my friction is $f_r=\mu\Delta mg$

If I apply Newton laws to the whole plank, I get:

$$-f_r=ma$$
$$-\mu\Delta mg=ma$$
$$-\mu mg\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}=ma$$

$$a=-\mu g\frac{\Delta \ell}{L}$$

The increase in $x$ of the plank is $\Delta \ell$ so I can write this as:

$$x''=-x\frac{\mu g}{L} \Longrightarrow x''+x\frac{\mu g}{L}=0 $$

It's a simple harmonic oscillator, so we can solve this given some initial conditions. Now if $x(0)=0$ and $v(0)=v_o$. Now the general solution of the simple harmonic oscillator is:

$$x(t)=A\cos(w_ot)+B\sin(w_ot),\text{  where  } w_o=\sqrt{\frac{g\mu}{L}} $$
$$v(t)=-Aw_o\sin(w_ot)+Bw_o\cos(w_ot)$$

**Edit: Correction of initial conditions**

$\star$ I realized that $x(0)=0$ , because I defined $x:=\Delta \ell$. As  $\Delta \ell$ have to start from $0$ when the plank start to touch the friction floor $x(0)=0$

Now we find $A$ and $B$ with the initial conditions:
$$0=x(0)=A\cos(0)+B\sin(0) \Longrightarrow A=0$$
$$v_o=v(0)=-A w_o\sin(0)+B w_o\cos(0) \Longrightarrow B=\frac{v_o}{w_o}$$

Now we want to know when does the plank stop, that is fond $t$ when $v=0$:

$$v(t)=0=v_o\cos(w_ot)$$

This mean that the argument of $\cos()$ should be $\pi/2$ because if its greater the bar would be moving backwards and that doesn't make sense.

$$w_ot=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$t_{\text{stop}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{L}{g \mu}}$$

But this result is kind of non-intuitive, because no matter the initial velocity of the plank if the plank is still in contact with the frictionless floor at the moment of $v=0$, it will always stop in $t_{\text{stop}}$. **Is this result right ?**

Of course the distance of the plank will be different if $v_o$ is different as you can see:

$$x_{\text{stop}}=\frac{v_0}{w_o} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$x_{\text{stop}}=v_0 \sqrt{\frac{L}{g \mu}}$$

Now I must divide in two cases if $x(t_{\text{stop}})\leq L$ and $x(t_{\text{stop}})>L$, the previous solution was the case $x(t_{\text{stop}})\leq L$ Now if $x(t_{\text{stop}})=L$ :

$$L=v_0 \sqrt{\frac{L}{g \mu}} \Rightarrow v_o= \sqrt{L g \mu}$$

Now if $v_o> \sqrt{\frac{L}{g \mu}}$ the motion will be described by to solutions:

The first part when the plank is moving in both surfaces and the change happens when:

$$x(t_{\text{change}})=L=\frac{v_0}{w_o} \sin(w_o t_{\text{change}})$$
$$t_{\text{change}}= \sin^{-1}( \frac{\sqrt{L g \mu}}{v_o}) \sqrt{\frac{L}{g \mu}}  $$

Now the velocity it will acquire will be, $v(t_{\text{change}})=v_o\cos(w_o t _{\text{change}})$

This two initial conditions,$x(t_{\text{change}})$ and $v(t_{\text{change}})$   are enough to completely describe the motion where the acceleration is defined as :

$$a=-g\mu$$

Finally this solution is almost trivial.

Comment: The system only obeys the harmonic oscillator equation while some of the plank remains on the smooth surface. Once the plank has completely crossed onto the rough side the equation of motion changes to $\ddot{x} = -\mu mg$ i.e. the dceleration is constant. There will be a critical value of $v_0$ above which the plank crosses completely onto the rough surface. That's whay as you take $v_0 \rightarrow \infty$ your SMO derived equation of motion gives silly answers.

Comment: John is right - your equation is only valid as long as part of the plank is still in the frictionless region. Once it crosses entirely, the force does not change with position. You should be able to finish it from there.

Comment: @JohnRennie I solved the problem fixing some initial conditions but I got to a really weird result, no matter the initial velocity of the plank, if the plank is still in contact with the frictionless floor at the moment of $v=0$, it will always stop in $t_{\text{stop}}$ , "specified in the question". **Is this result right ?**,

Comment: @Floris I'm still wondering about the last question: 

>>I solved the problem fixing some initial conditions but I got to a really weird result, no matter the initial velocity of the plank, if the plank is still in contact with the frictionless floor at the moment of $v=0$, it will always stop in $t_\text{stop}$ , "specified in the question". Is this result right ?,

Comment: That seems strange but it makes sense - that's exactly how simple harmonic notion works. Think about the motion of a pendulum - the time from the middle of the swing to the time it stops is independent of the amplitude (velocity at center) as long as the small angle approximation holds. Counterintuitive but true - you did well.